# Can you prove that the integral below, with a vectorial field, is zero?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, dirac-delta

If $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$ is a vector field limited in infinity. Prove that the integral below is zero:
\begin{equation}
\int{\left(\vec{J}\left(\vec{r}'\right)\cdot\nabla\right)\cdot\left(\nabla\frac{1}{\vert\vec{r} - \vec{r}'\vert}\right)}d^3r'
\end{equation}
where the integral is over all space. 
I have tried to use the condition $\nabla^2(\frac{1}{r}) = -4\pi \delta(\vec{r})$ of the Dirac delta. You can use integration by parts and then the Divergent Theorem. These are the tip's that my friends told me, but I still couldn't answer with a good proof.

Comment: I think you have too many dots. $\nabla \frac{1}{|\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r}'|}$ is a vector, but then when you take the divergence of it you end up with a scalar which you can't then take the dot product of with $\overrightarrow{J}$, a vector.

Comment: @BaronMingus: That's not right. $\vec J\cdot\nabla$ is the scalar differential operator $J_x\partial_x+J_y\partial_y+J_z\partial_z$, which can be applied to the gradient vector $\nabla \frac{1}{|\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r}'|}$.

Comment: @joriki You're still taking the dot product of a scalar and vector. I realize now I'm probably being pedantic given that there's only one way it can be read, but I was confused at first.

Comment: @BaronMingus: It's quite usual to denote non-dot products by multiplication dots (though it's misleading here and I wouldn't write i that way).

Comment: @joriki you will actually end up with different integrands depending on which of the dots corresponds to a dot product and which one a multiplication by a scalar. I'm going to assume the second dot is the dot product given OP mentions using an identity involving the laplacian, which is what I assume he means by $\nabla^2$.

Comment: @BaronMingus: I don't see a way of interpreting that dot as a dot product that would be consistent with the parentheses. In fact as far as I can tell there's only a single interpretation of the entire expression that's compatible with the parentheses. The Laplacian could come appear in the course of the solution; it doesn't have to be there already. Also, under this interpretation, the integral would evaluate to $-4\pi\vec J(\vec r)$, and I see no reason why that should be zero.

Comment: @joriki I think like you said. If is a simple dot product that goes to de laplacian this integral would not give zero as a result (sorry for my english)

Comment: @joriki Yes, I'm on board now. Thanks for clearing that up.